# Creating an element with createElement result on a div with a rigth margin filling the screen

Tags: javascript, html

Im triyig to create a div with createElement(9, with a bunch of div's inside but the inside div's result with a strange margin that fills the entire screen causing the divs to "wrap" below. Im using typeScript and customElements (webComponents).

This is my code:

```
const sectionPrueba = this.ownerDocument.createElement("section")
const pixelPrueba = this.ownerDocument.createElement("section")
pixelPrueba.style.backgroundColor = "black"
pixelPrueba.style.width = "10px"
pixelPrueba.style.height = "10px"


this.shadowRoot?.appendChild(pixelPrueba)
```

I was triying to create the divs and stock them verticaly in a div, but the margin makes them to "wrap" below creating the divs on a vertical line.

Comment: I'm not seeing "a bunch of divs inside" here, just `sectionPrueba` and `pixelPrueba`, but you're not doing anything with the former. Using the regular DOM, pixelPrueba shows up as a black square.